# Set cookies in WKHTTPCookieStorage iOS11

Tags: ios, cookies, ios11, wkwebview

I created a method to set cookies from HTTPCookieStorage into WKHTTPCookieStorage, as it seems this api is full async so i created an async method that sets the cookies in wkHTTPCookieStorage.

```
    func copyCookiesToWKStore(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if let httpCookies: [HTTPCookie] = self.httpCookieStorage.cookies {
        print("updating wkCookies with httpCookies: \(httpCookies)")
        func copyCookiesAsync(index: Int, cookieHandler: SDCookiesHandler?) {
            if let cookieHandler = cookieHandler, index < httpCookies.count {
                let cookie = httpCookies[index]
                cookieHandler.wkCookieStore.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: {
                    print("set cookie in Cookie Storage: \(cookie)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        copyCookiesAsync(index: index + 1, cookieHandler: cookieHandler)
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                completion()
            }
        }
        weak var cookieHandler = self
        copyCookiesAsync(index: 0, cookieHandler: cookieHandler)
    } else {
        completion()
    }
}
```

which is then synced and insert when we are going to load a webview.load

```
wkCookiesHandler.copyCookiesToWKStore { [weak self] in
            if let weakSelf = self {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    weakSelf.webView.load(cookiesRequest)
                }

            } else {
                print("self is null")
            }
        }
```

However when webview calls the decidePolicyFor navigationAction method, the cookies in WKCookieStorage are not fully synced at this point.

I have read in some posts that WKProcessPool has its own cycle to sync cookies, and that resetting it, causes cookies to sync with wkwebview, but i found that i am in existent webview flow, it causes weird artifacts with the webview.

Has anyone started using WKCookieStorage api, and how can one keep cookies inserted in this api, visible by the WKWebview.